# Multiple XMPP servers to handle upstream GCM messages

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, xmpp

I want to have multiple XMPP servers listening on upstream GCM messages for load balancing and fault tolerance. If I connect two servers to the same sender ID, would google automatically split the messages between them?

Answer (score 0):

It's stated in [Implementing an XMPP Connection Server](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs) that, periodically, CCS needs to close down a connection to perform load balancing to control messages.

> Before it closes the connection, CCS sends a CONNECTION_DRAINING message to indicate that the connection is being drained and will be closed soon. "Draining" refers to shutting off the flow of messages coming into a connection, but allowing whatever is already in the pipeline to continue. When you receive a CONNECTION_DRAINING message, you should immediately begin sending messages to another CCS connection, opening a new connection if necessary. You should, however, keep the original connection open and continue receiving messages that may come over the connection (and ACKing them)—CCS handles initiating a connection close when it is ready.

I might be wrong but what I understand is that splitting of messages is not done since there's only one active connection. Sending of messages to another server starts as soon as CCS sends message that connection will be closed.

Comment: Firebase document says "For each sender ID, FCM allows 1000 connections in parallel." Are these only for sending downstream messages?